# How to not load api from a given URL?

Tags: manual-testing, api-testing

A customer wants a specific error code when certain apis fail to load. I am thinking of blocking the URL where apis come from.

- I was given the task to verify our developers have implemented the right error code as per our customers request.

I have tried to redirect the URL to localhost in my hosts file (I am using a MacBook), but it did not work.

Comment: I have voted to close this as offtopic since this has nothing to do with Quality Assurance. However even if you will post your question somewhere else I would recommend to add more details like what you mean under *load api from url*? Since noramlly one does not load API from URL but calls a function of API via URL. So in your question it is worth improving the problem statement. What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlexeyR., thanks, I have added my reason to ask this question on QA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) as a proxy that will let you filter and change your web requests. I'm not familiar with exactly how it is on a Mac, but on a PC, you can edit the FiddlerScript and they have an example on how to break specific requests:

```
// Sample Rule: Break requests for URLs containing "/sandbox/"
if (oSession.uriContains("/sandbox/")) {
    oSession.oFlags["x-breakrequest"] = "yup";  // Existence of the x-breakrequest flag creates a breakpoint; the "yup" value is unimportant.
}
```

That should be enough of a starting point to get you to mung the request and response however you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a browser extension instead?

- switcheroo, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg?hl=en

With switcheroo, basically, you will need to:

1. Enable this extension
2. Go to the developer tool -> Network tab, look for the URL (you are more likely already know which URL you need)
3. Copy and paste this URL into switcheroo, and redirect it to a silly / random URL.
4. APIs should fail to load

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac you can also check out [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/). It is a robust proxy tool that allows you to monitor an manipulate traffic on your mac as well as other devices (such as mobile or set-top devices) on your network.

Look at this answer for specifics on rewriting a response with a specific status code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667949/2588811